# How to use the method getHealth() in Bukkit using Heroes

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Basically I have started updating a lot of Heroes spells to 1.7.2 and this update broke the .getHealth() and .getMaxHealth(). I am trying to fix it but I do not know how to. If anyone has some advice or samples I will be in debt. I will place some code where I use the .getHealth() method.
this is the link of the error: http://puu.sh/7BrEP.png. It is saying this method is ambigous for that type.

```
public void tickHero(Hero hero) {
    if ( hero.getPlayer().getHealth() - damage > 1) {
        addSpellTarget(hero.getPlayer(), plugin.getCharacterManager().getHero(caster));
        damageEntity(hero.getPlayer(), caster, damage, DamageCause.MAGIC);
        //hero.getPlayer().damage(damage, caster);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will you pay back the debt?

Comment: With gratitude for eternity and help if I can offer it

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. How exactly is it broken? Are you getting any errors? If so, seeing your stack trace would make helping easier.

Comment: I am still learning how to explain my errors. I have eddited the error that I get. It s saying that it is ambigous and I do not know how to make it choose the correct one.

Comment: Try casting the player to a living entity, like this:

`((LivingEntity)hero.getPlayer())` then using that to get the health:

`((LivingEntity)hero.getPlayer()).getHealth()`. It would really help to know your stacktrace (shown in console), and the entire code for that class.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.7.2, there are two `getHealth()` and `getMaxHealth()` methods. This is becaue of the way Bukkit handled Minecraft changing the way entity health is stored in 1.6. You can read more about this [here](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/oops-i-didnt-break-your-plugins-ambiguous-gethealth.156975/).

If you aren't using any NMS code, you should use the bukkit.jar in your build path as opposed to craftbukkit.jar. This should resolve your issue easily enough.

If you do need NMS code, you need to have both bukkit.jar AND craftbukkit.jar in your build path. Furthermore, you have to have bukkit.jar above craftbukkit.jar in the build path for it to work.